# How to add my own gifs to Nougat keyboard gif search?

Tags: gboard, 7.1-nougat

I have a Nexus 6 running Nougat. I love the relatively new gif search in the native messaging app's keyboard, but I'm wondering if there's any way to add my own gifs to it.

Yes, I know I can just send gifs directly as a file by choosing from a source like Dropbox or Photos, but there are a few I use on a regular basis as responses, and I'd like to be able to have them at hand without having to take those extra steps. Yes, I'm lazy.